# nginx upstream proxy_pass not working for heroku?

Tags: nginx, heroku, proxy, load-balancing, proxypass

The below nginx config is working fine **if I hardcode** my herokuapp(backend API) in proxy_pass section:

```
http { 
    server {
        listen 8080;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://my-app.herokuapp.com;
        }
    }
}

events { }
```

However if I try to add this in the **upstream directive**, its going to `404` page. I want to add this in upstream directive because I have other herokuapps as well where I want to load balance my requests.

This is the config which is not working:

```
http { 

    upstream backend {
        server my-app.herokuapp.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }
}

events { }
```

These are all the things I tried after checking other SO answers:

- add Host header while proxy passing. `proxy_set_header Host $host;`
- add an extra slash at the end of backend.
- In upstream directive, add `server my-app.herokuapp.com:80` instead of just `server my-app.herokuapp.com`
- In upstream directive, add `server my-app.herokuapp.com:443` instead of just `server my-app.herokuapp.com`. This gives timeout probably because heroku doesn't allow 443(or maybe I didn't configure it).

Comment: Ok, you are getting `404`, what's in `access.log` or `error.log`? Looks like location or some path might be messed up.

Comment: access log unfortunately doesnt have any information. It just prints 404 and 563 bytes(heroku's default 404 HTML page size). This is what I have in access.log `127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2022:15:47:37 -0400] "POST /run HTTP/1.1" 404 563 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0"`

Comment: The weird thing is that it works if I hardcode the URL(as shown in first config in the question). However it fails when I use upstream directive. If this worked, I wanted to have multiple servers to load balance. But single upstream server itself is not working.

Comment: There is something wrong with your `my-app.herokuapp.com` backend configuration, could you show it?

Comment: Which file in that herokuapp? The app is a java spring boot app and its working fine. In fact the first config as I showed in the question works for me. Only when I put it in upstream directive, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Issue: I was adding the wrong host. For heroku, for some reason you need to add host header with value as exactly what your app name is.

If your herokuapp name is `my-app.herokuapp.com`, then you need to add this line for sure:

```
proxy_set_header Host my-app.herokuapp.com;
```

Full working config below:

```
http { 

    upstream backend {
        server my-app.herokuapp.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header Host my-app.herokuapp.com;
        }
    }
}

events { }
```

Comment: For sure, you have sent requests to wrong host, glad you solved your problem.